# Require Help Writing Bash Script to Compare Mounted Network Mounts MAC OSX

Tags: macos, bash, osx-yosemite

I am trying to write a bash script that will base the outcome depending on what Network Share is mounted,

I have 3 possible network mounts and require 3 different outcomes depending on what is mounted.

I have no experience in writing bash but i am able to fill in the rest once i have the IF statement setup, i just cant find anywhere to help me compare what mounts are mounted

This is what i am looking for

```
    IF [Network Mount 1 is mounted] then 

    Copy File 1

    Else IF [Network Mount 2 is mounted] then

    Copy File 2

    Else [Network Mount 3 is mounted] Then

    Copy File 3
```

I'm Stuck!

Please Help or guide me.

UPDATE:
So I think i have been comparing the wrong piece of information to achieve my goal,

As i'm hoping to run this script as a login hook i think its better i compare the users SMB Home Directory rather than mount as it wont be mounted when the script runs.

I can get the network home directory with this line of code

```
dscl . read /Users/$USER SMBHome
```

I now want to compare this against 3 possible SMB File Servers

FS02/StudentsFolders$
FS03/StaffFolders$
FS03/TeachersFolders$

on a wildcard comparison as the SMB path will include the users name also, so this is what i have so far

```
#!/bin/bash

UsersHome = dscl . read /Users/$USER SMBHome;

# First Argument #  if [[ $UserHome == *"FS02/StudentsFolders$"* ]] then   echo "Make Changes to Plist";

# Seconde Argument #  else if [[ $UserHome == *"fs03/Stafffolders$"* ]] then    echo "Make different Changes to Plist";

# Third Argument #  else 

Echo "Make Changes to the plist";
```

I know there will be Syntax Errors Please feel free to point them out.

Is this the correct way to go about my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Mounted volumes are usually found in the `/Volumes` directory. You might want something like

```
if [ -d /Volumes/DiskOne ]; then # Is DiskOne mounted?
   ...
elif [ -d /Volumes/DiskTwo ]; then # Is DiskTwo mounted
   ...
else
   ...
fi
```

Comment: @EtanReisner Unlike Unix/Linux, OSX sees that mountpoints don't exist when nothing is mounted. Go figure :-)

Comment: Some double quotes around `"/Volumes/DiskOne"` would set a good example here, although not strictly necessary, since Mac users often use spaces, as well as Apple ... e.g, `Macintosh HD` and `Time Machine`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Heh. Unix/Linux can see that too you just won't be able to mount anything at that location until you "fix" that "problem". =)

Comment: Thanks Chaps, Il try your inputs tomorrow and let you know how I get on :)